# how to authenticate user using spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I wants to implement spring security log in and log out so I have tried following things ,
Spring-context.xml:

```
<http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated"/>  <!-- this  means all URL in this app will be checked if user is authenticated -->
        <form-login/> <!--  -->
        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url=""/>
 </http>
 <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider> 
            <user-service>
                <user name="sachin" password="sachin123" authorities="Admin"/>
            </user-service>
 </authentication-provider>
```

spring-servlet.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.hrportal.controller" />
    </context:annotation-config>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </property>
            </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**"  location="/images/"/>
    <mvc:resources location="/css/**" mapping="/css/"/>
    <mvc:resources location="/css/**" mapping="/css/"/>
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

I am doing database connection and access manually that is why I am not able to implement the log in and log out using spring security.

I am using the following class to connect with database manually :

```
private static Connection con = null;

public static Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        if (con == null) {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/portal",
                    "root", "root");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return con;
}

}
```

can anyone explain me to solve this..

Comment: Could you please explain what the problem is?

Comment: @geoand, Actually I am new to spring technology.....and sevlet very well and I wants to use log and log out service so I followed some online tutorials but could not understand completly.

Comment: and I am doing manually to authenticate user so Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220556/how-to-implement-custom-authentication-in-spring-security-3. It probably fits your needs

Answer (score 0):

Try using spring roo, this rad tool help you to generate code and configure spring security automatically.
http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/beginning.html